Issue in reading behavex.ini file with behavex python
I am working on creating a framework using behavex-python.
I have below structure:
project_root
    helpers
    resources
    tests
        features
        steps
        pages
        environment.py
    conf_behavex.cfg

The content of conf_behavex.cfg is:
[behavex]
tags = @XX
parallel_processes = 4
show_progress = true

[output]
path = report/behavex_report

On executing behavex tests/features -c=conf_behavex.cfg only CONFIG path and OUTPUT path is updated but rest is not changed at all.
https://github.com/prashant1507/python-behave-bdd-selenium-ui-framework/tree/practice
The project is available here. Its only missing conf_behavex.cfg rest everything is same as mentioned above
Please help me !!! Thanks
I tried to use .ini, .cfg files but no success
